Why doesn't currentUser return correct permissions?
This happens a lot of the time in my custom Drupal 10 module and I cannot figure out why. Custom permissions return wrong value with currentUser but returns correct value when loading user by uid. $this->currentUser is valid and the correct account. What's the issue/cause and resolution?
Example:
Wrong value:
$hasViewPermission = $this->currentUser->hasPermission(
    sprintf('view %s categories', $termGroup)
);
// false

Correct value
$user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
$hasViewPermission = $user->hasPermission(
    sprintf('view %s categories', $termGroup)
);
// true

Role config
permissions:
  ...
  - 'view EDITORIAL categories'

Edit: added demo of currentUser initialisation
    protected $currentUser;

    public function __construct(
        array $configuration, $plugin_id,
        $plugin_definition,
        array $serializer_formats,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        AccountProxyInterface $current_user,
        Request $current_request
    ) {
        parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $serializer_formats, $logger);
        $this->currentUser = $current_user;
        $this->currentRequest = $current_request;
    }


    public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition)
    {
        return new static(
            $configuration,
            $plugin_id,
            $plugin_definition,
            $container->getParameter('serializer.formats'),
            $container->get('logger.factory')->get('custom_rest'),
            $container->get('current_user'),
            $container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()
        );
    }


This question is not answerable with the given context. Obvisouly $this->currentUser from 1st example is not the same as $user from 2nd example. Blind guessing: either $this->currentUser  was never initialized, or $this->currentUser is incorrectly cached.

Is $termGroup set to EDITORIAL in both cases?

@monalisa yeah permission is the same. currentUser is initialised and all good. I think maybe cache like @Hudri mentioned. Flushing caches doesn't make a difference though. What other caches are there for user object?

We need some context as to where your code exists. Also have to dumped these objects to compare them? They may not be the same object. This could be https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3182145, for example.

@AbdulSadikYalcin Can you provide context about where $this->currentUser is getting called from? Service, controller, form, etc? And does your editor hint what the type of $this->currentUser is? It is a little hard to guess here, but I suspect you have an Account and not a User. This is a really confusing part of core, where when you have an Account you need to load the full user for some scenarios.

@mpdonadio added code of initialisation. What you just said makes absolute sense re Account vs User. Maybe that is the issue. (Note: I ain't a Drupal expert)
